# 404 error from node access hook

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I have `node_access` hook in a module. I tried to prevent anonymous user from access unpublished node like the following:

```
function MODULE_NAME_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
   global $user; 
if ($op == 'view' && $node->status == 0 ){
     return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }  
}
```

This is working fine and redirect to access denied custom page. However, I would like it to be redirect to the custom 404 not found page. i.e the http response to be 404. I tried to find any replacement of `NODE_ACCESS_DENY` but I could not able to find anything.

I tried to use `drupal_not_found()` but it generates Server Error on the server.

Also, I would like to know, if there a method or property of the `$user` object that determine if the user is anonymous user or not. I find that there is `user_is_anonymous()` but I could not know how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drupal_goto("custom 404 page")` to redirect a user to your custom page. For your second question you can check if user is anonymous using this condition. `if($user->uid == 0)`

Thus your hook can be rewritten like this.

```
function MODULE_NAME_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  global $user;
  if ($op == 'view' && $node->status == 0 && $user->uid == 0){
    drupal_goto("custom_404_page");
   }
}
```

See here for [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) documentation

Note: This function has been removed in Drupal 8. In Drupal 8 you can do this by this way.

```
return new RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url('user.page'));
```

or this way 
`use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

```
class MyControllerClass extends ControllerBase {
   public function foo() {
   //...
   return $this->redirect('user.page');
  }
}`
```

See here for [Drupal 8 redirect info](https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537)

Comment: `hook_node_access()` is not supposed to call `drupal_goto()`; it would redirect users in the wrong moment, and it would cause problems during cron tasks. `hook_node_access()` is not necessary called when a user is viewing a node.

Answer (score 1):

`hook_node_access()` is not necessarily invoked when a user is viewing a node page: It is invoked from [`node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7) which in turn is called in different circumstances.

- [`node_file_download_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_file_download_access/7) uses it to verify a user can download a file attached to a node
- [`node_form_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/7) uses it to decide if the user can be redirected to the page showing the node or redirect the user to the front page
- [`translation_node_prepare()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_node_prepare/7) uses it to initialize some node fields related to translations

In all those cases, the functions are calling `node_access('view')` and redirecting the logged-in user or showing a 404 page would disrupt the normal Drupal behavior and would avoid Drupal completes what it is doing.

The only way to be sure a user is going to view a node is intercepting when the page callback for node/%node is being called. You cannot rely on [`node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) being called when a user is going to view a node, since `node_view()` is called also from cron tasks (see [`_node_index_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/_node_index_node/7), which is indirectly called from [`search_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_cron/7); this also means `hook_node_view()` cannot be used to redirect users while they are supposedly seeing a node page, since this is not true.

This would mean to implement `hook_menu_alter()` to change the page callback and the access callback of node/%node. You need to change the access callback because the default one is `node_access()` and users would still get a 403 error if they try to access directly a URL for an unpublished node. Since you are interested in showing a 404 page instead of a 403 page just for anonymous users, you could use the following code for the access callback.

```
function mymodule_node_access($op, $node) {
  if ($GLOBALS['user']->uid == 0 && $op == 'view' && $node->status == 0) {
    // We will return a 404 error to the user.
    return TRUE;
  }

  return node_access($op, $node);
}
```

Since you are just using the access callback for node/%node, its code doesn't need to check the operation, since it is going to be *view*.

```
function mymodule_node_access($op, $node) {
  if ($GLOBALS['user']->uid == 0 && $node->status == 0) {
    // We will return a 404 error to the user.
    return TRUE;
  }

  return node_access($op, $node);
}
```

The page callback would be similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_node_page_view($node) {
  if ($GLOBALS['user']->uid == 0 && $node->status == 0) {
    drupal_not_found();
  }

  return node_page_view($node);
}
```

#### Notes

- Since the access callback is returning `TRUE` for anonymous users, any link to unpublished nodes will be shown to anonymous users. This is something it cannot be avoided, since Drupal uses an access callback for two different purposes.
- The alternative would be generally replacing a 403 error with a 404 error, but that would means it happens for every page. Checking the path being accessed would avoid making it happen for administrative pages, for example; checking for anonymous users would avoid it for authenticated users. (If I find a way to do this, I will updated my answer.)

As for [`user_is_anonymous()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_anonymous/7), it only works with the global `$user` and it is an hack for a specific case. The function you should call is [`user_is_logged_in()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7), which still works with the global `$user`.
Since the function has been removed from Drupal 8, I would rather check the user ID is 0, to understand if a user is anonymous user; in Drupal 8, you would change the code, but you would need to do that even when using `user_is_anonymous()` or `user_is_logged_in()`.